# In Julia, how do I run an external program and process its output line by line?

Tags: pipe, julia

I tried

```
for line in readlines(`cmd`)
```

where cmd is the name of the external command, but this waits for all the output to finish to start reading.

What I want is something similar to Python's

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in p.stdout
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```rb
julia> open(`ls`) do io
           while !eof(io)
               line = readline(io)
               @show line
           end
       end
line = "bar"
line = "baz.txt"
line = "foo.sh"
```